# Automatically adding a calendar feed (.ics) to android/iphone though link or barcode

Tags: android, iphone, barcode, google-calendar-api, icalendar

On my website I want to share a link or show a barcode that directs to a google calendar. Is it possible to have the calendar added as a live feed to the visitors smartphone when they click the link, or scan the barcode?

I've searched the web but couldn't find anything helpful. Hope this is an appropriate question.

Comment: There's no activity (or other component) that listens for the "text/calendar" MIME-type in the default Calendar or CalendarProvider; this doesn't mean that there couldn't be 3rd party addons that supply this service - but for the average Android 2.3 (or earlier) phone I wouldn't expect to find this (compared to contacts (text/x-vcard) which has a VIEW action defined in the Contacts app).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jens. But, I'm afraid I do not understand. Is it not possible to subscribe to a live ics feed by clicking a link on Android?

Comment: Clicking on a link in a WebView / browser typically triggers an Intent aptly named android.intent.action.VIEW. If no application has an intent-filter for the combination of android.intent.action.VIEW and the MIME-type of the ics file (typically text/calendar) nothing will happen - and the default applications you'd expect be handling such intents do not have any such intent-filters. There may still be 3rd party addons/applications that declare an intent-filter for iCalendar.